# Unable to use postMessage() from a child "localhost" window to an intranet host window in Edge

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

I have two web pages - Host and Child (see below). The Host web page is hosted on a server that is on my local network. The Child page is hosted on my computer. The Host page opens up the child page, using “localhost” in a `window.open()` call. The Child page then posts a message back to the Host page using the `window.postMessage()` method.

In IE and Chrome, the postMessage() works from the “localhost” page to the page that is hosted on the other server. In Edge, it does not work. The “message” event is not even fired on the host page.

Now, if I put the Host page on a server that is not on my local network, the postMessage() method does work and the “message” event is fired. IE had a concept of intranet vs. internet sites, and I wonder if Edge has the same concept except that there is no way of configuring it.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here or any way to get the message to work from the "localhost" page to the host page?

Thanks!

Host page (hosted on other server on my network):

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Post Message Test</title>
    <script>
        function setup() {
            window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
                var messagesEl = document.getElementById("messages");
                messagesEl.innerHTML += "- Received message from " + event.origin + "<br/>";
            });
        }

        function openChildWindow() {
            window.open('http://localhost/sandbox/PostMessageTest_child/child.html', '_blank', 'left=100;top=100;width=100;height=100');
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="setup()">
    <button onclick="openChildWindow()">Open Child Window</button>
    <p id="messages"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Child page (child.html hosted on localhost):

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script>
        function postMessage() {
            window.opener.postMessage("Test Message", "*");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="postMessage()">Post Message</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try 3rd argument ( transfer )? it might help

Comment: there is currently an issue where window.opener is undefined in Edge (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8710056/) - are you certain that is not the issue you are seeing?

Comment: @Patrick Yes - I actually am running into that issue. Thanks!